# Sigma Notation in Loop analysis

Tags: algorithm, operation

Our professor provided a few handouts to help with our homework in my Algorithms and Data Structures class.

The first one is a review of some Sigma Notation and associated properties. This, of course, lists:

[image]

and

[image]

Another handout had examples of how to use Sigma Notation to count the number of operations in a loop.

This handout states the pseudocode:

"for i [image]1 to n do:"

Would translate to

[image]

I understand 1 operation to initialize the loop (1+) but why in the heck do we suddenly sum to n+1? Wouldn't we just sum from 0 to n with the result being

[image]

I have also emailed the professor and the TA, but both have been less than helpful. So, any additional insight that could be provided would be greatly appreciated. This is the one thing that is really holding me up and it is very frustrating. I mean, am I crazy? Or are the notes wrong?

EDIT: My apologies; I had "for 0 <- 1 to n, do:". It should read "for i <- 1 to n do:"

Comment: You also have to do a check afterwards for the final condition that fails. For example `i < n`, the case where it actually is `n` and then aborts. That is the (n+1)-th iteration. Maybe thats meant. Hard to say without the actual code though.

Comment: In any case, It does not matter at all, since all of that is just constant overhead anyways. So just `O(n)`.

Comment: `for 0 <- 1 to n do` - what does this mean, specifically why is 0 on the left here instead of a variable name? And if the loop is from 1 to n, the sum should be from 1 to n, not 0 to n + 1. If there is an extra cost for the (n+1)th comparison when the loop terminates, that should be outside of the summation since you would presumably want to be summing over the cost of the loop body for each iteration, and there are n iterations, not n+1 or n+2. So it seems to me that either you are misunderstanding something, or the notes have a mistake or two. Your teachers should be responsible either way.

Comment: Note that the notation is not 100% accurate. It is not `foo = O(...)`, it is `foo element of O(...)`. `O` and similar define a set of functions, emphasis on set. People tend to forget or not care.

Answer (score 1):

How do you exit the loop?  You increment to `n+1`, check the condition, and then exit.

It may help to consider a concrete value of 3 for n.  Here are the operations.

```
set i to 0
set i to i+1 (1) and test whether i (1) is > n (3)
set i to i+1 (2) and test whether i (2) is > n (3)
set i to i+1 (3) and test whether i (3) is > n (3)
set i to i+1 (4) and test whether i (4) is > n (3)
```

And now you see that the 1 is for initialization, and there are 4 attempted increments before you're done looping.

The loop body will, of course, also happen `n+1` times.

Comment: In the loop `for i <- 1 to n` the loop body should happen `n` times, not `n + 1` times; and the summation is for `i = 0` to `n+1`, so that will actually sum `n + 2` terms. I think it is a mistake in the handout, especially since `for 0 <- 1 to n` makes it look like they are trying to use an index variable named `0`.

Answer (score 0):

My TA finally provided an enlightening response:

When the pseudocode says "for i <- 1 to n do:"

This would be the equivalent of writing a for loop such that:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++);
```

In which case we are counting comparisons `i<=n` *including n*. So, the loop would terminate after n+1 comparisons. The n+1'th comparison is the exit condition. Hence, we end up with:

[image]

Similarly, if the pseudocode reads "for i<-1 to n-1 do:" this would be equivalent to:

```
for (i = 1; i < n; i++);
```

So, we would perform comparisons `i<n` up to, *but NOT including n*. The n'th comparison would be the exit condition. So, we would end up with:

[image]

I think that's pretty much what most of you were saying, I just had a difficult time wrapping my mind around it without an actual `code` example of what the pseudocode was saying. I don't know if this is a convention across all algorithm analysis classes, or just ours. But I do want to thank everyone for their help!